# I want to travel by rail in Europe by Eurail

Tags: trains, paris, switzerland, austria, eurail

I want to travel by rail in Europe in 3 connecting countries for 11 days. 
So I wanted to ask, is it good to book tickets in advance or is good to book from station A to B?

My itinerary starts from Germany on 29th June and then 1st Austria, 2nd Switzerland and 3rd Paris (France).

I will travel 30th June, 1st July, 2nd July in Vienna, Innsbruck & Salzburg. 3rd July, 4th July, and 5th July in Zurich Geneva. I will travel to Paris 7th July onwards.

Kindly suggest me an better option what to do?

Comment: Are you asking whether to buy a pass or separate tickets for each journey? Are you eligible for age-related discounts?

Comment: It may also depend how much you value flexibility in your journey times. A pass offers you've a choice and can be confirmed last minutes but individual tickets (esspecily cheap ones) may be fixed to one train.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options for you:

**First the flexible option:**

You can book all your tickets at the Railwaystations and there is no need for advanced bookings.

Advantages:

- Flexible

Disadvantages:

- Expensive
- Waiting in line at the counter

**The flexible online option:**

You can buy your tickets on the go through the ÖBB, SBB and SNCF website or app.

Advantages:

- Flexible

Disadvantages:

- As Expensive as at the counter

**Pre-Booking option:**
When you are a little bit flexible in your itinary and you book in advance, you can reserve heavy discounts though the following programs:

- [ÖBB Sparschiene for Austria](http://www.oebb.at/en/angebote-ermaessigungen/sparschiene)
- [SBB Sparbillet for Switzerland](https://www.sbb.ch/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets-for-switzerland/supersaver-tickets.html?WT.mc_id=cpc_sparbillette_gsn_de&WT.srch=1&wt_campaign=DE_Ticketshop_GSN_CH-CH_Brand_TIC_Sparbillett_MIX&wt_adgroup=Sparbillett_EXA&wt_keyword=sbb%20sparbillet&wt_matchtype=e&wt_contentlanguage=de)
- [SNCF OUI for France](https://en.oui.sncf/en/deals)

Advantages:

- Sometimes up to 75% cheaper

Disadvantages:

- No flexibility
- Not all connections are eligable for discounts

**Interrail option:**

You can buy a interrail pass on the [interrail website](https://www.interrail.eu/en/interrail-passes/global-pass).

If you are aged between 12-27 the following prices apply:

- 208€ for 5 days in an 15 day period
- 255€ for 7 days in an 31 day period
- 305€ for 10 days in an 31 day period

If you are aged between 27-59 the following prices apply:

- 269€ for 5 days in an 15 day period
- 320€ for 7 days in an 31 day period
- 381€ for 10 days in an 31 day period

Advantages:

- Cheap for long travels
- Flexible

Disadvantages:

- Expensive for short travel

Comment: InterRail is for Europeans and people who have or will be residents of Europe, mostly the participating countries but also a few more in the general area. All others can use Eurail but not InterRail. And Eurail is often more expensive.